# Differential inclusions for distributions

Tags: differential-equations, foliations, tangent-distributions, set-valued-analysis

Given a set valued function $F$ such that for every $x\in M$ (a manifold) we have that $F(x)\subset T_xM$, a [differential inclusion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_inclusion) is the "equation", $\dot{x} \in F(x)$.

I was wondering if someone has studied an analog of this for distributions, that is, consider a function such that $F(x)\subset (T_xM)^k$ and search for foliations such that in every point are tangent to the span of an element of $F(x)$.

I've tried googleing some similar names and could not find anything, but maybe here someone knows the key-word I am looking for. Also if there is any reference that would be good.

Comment: I don't know about in general, and I suspect this is not exactly what you are looking for, but a very similar problem is used for the method of characteristics for fully nonlinear first order partial differential equations. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monge_cone

Comment: Thanks, it was useful, though not exactly what I am looking for. 

Comment: Could you be more specific and tell us where you
are heading with this?  Could you give an 
example of what you are aiming for? By `distribution' do you mean
(a) a la Schwartz (eg. the Dirac delta function,etc) or 
(b) a subbundle of the tangent bundle?
And by $(T_x M)^k$ do you want symmetric powers $Symm^k (T_x M)$
or the full k-fold  tensor product?

If you mean $\Lambda^k (T_x M)$ then there is a literature, eg.
EDS by Bryant, Chern, et al (available free at the MSRI website)

Comment: Thanks for the references, I will look at them. By distribution, I mean a subbundle of the tangent bundle, I was wondering under which conditions one can integrate a distribution close to a given one. In http://mathoverflow.net/questions/37130/integrability-of-distributions-close-to-a-given-one I asked a similar question (based on my ignorance on the subject) and got an answer on some posible restrictions. I was wondering if someone had made a systematic study. 